# Mipmaps for Automatically Generated Texture Objects

Tags: libgdx

I want to generate mipmaps for textures generated by BitmapFont(FileHandle fontFile) constructor. Since it doesn't have that option, what can i do? Can I somehow deep copy the Texture object with mipmaps on or is there any other setting for using mipmaps after Texture object has already been initialized?

I want to use MipMapLinearLinear filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually load the font texture and give it to the `BitmapFont` contructor. Manually loading the texture will allow you to create mipmaps.

```
// true means generate mipmaps, important!
Texture fontImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("path/to/texture.png", true); 
fontImage.setMinFilter(TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear); // choose
fontImage.setMagFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest); // choose

// Bitmap font constructor takes a TextureRegion
TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(fontImage);
// false means dont flip. If your font looks strange try changing it to true.
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("path/to/font.fnt"), region, false);
```

Comment: My font consists of more than one Texture (5 png files) created by hiero.

Comment: @hellgasm _Five_ textures? I've never seen Hiero output more than one! The texture you use is the one specified under `file="some_texture.png"` in your `font.fnt` file. It should be somewhere at the top (probably line 3) of the file.